# Set duration of CakePHP session after successful login

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication, session-timeout

I have a CakePHP application that allows login using basic Auth. Each user has a specific role  such as "normal", "admin", etc..

Is there a way to set how long they can remain logged in for before it requires them to log back in?

Ideally, I'd like a regular user to be 1 hour, and an admin to be 14 hours.

Thanks!

Comment: [Sessions @ CookBook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html)

Comment: If I were to do something like CakeSession::write('Session.timeout', '60'); wouldn't that change the Session for everyone? It doesn't seem like it will be changing that specific user's session.

Comment: It wouldn't change the setting for everyone. It would just change the setting for that user's session. It only changes the session timeout in the current scope of things and won't change your config permanently.